# Passing variables through to GraphQL queries in external queries.ts file in React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm building a Next.js app using GraphQL with ApolloClient to handle the API requests. I had a page working correctly and retrieving the correct data when passing an ID to the Next.js methods getStaticPaths and getStaticProps using inline gql queries as shown below.

```
const { data } = await client.query({
  query: gql`
    query Page {
      page(id: "${slug}", idType: SLUG) {
        title
      }
    }
  `,
})
```

I have now started moving my gql queries to a separate queries.ts file and my issue is that I'm struggling to find a way to pass through the `slug` variable used in the request above. I tried the following but it did not work:

```
import { getPageQuery } from 'queries'

const { data } = await client.query({
  query: getPageQuery,
})
```

```
// queries.ts

const getPageQuery = (slug: string) => gql`
  query Page {
    page(id: "${slug}", idType: SLUG) {
      title
    }
  }
`
```

Looking for some information with regards to how I can keep my gql queries in a separate file and be able to pass in any dynamic data as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the slug variable.
eg:

```
export const getPageQuery = gql`
  query ($slug: String!) {
    page(where: { id: $slug }) {
      title
    }
  }
`;
```

Here is how you can call that request:

```
  const { data: res } = await client.query({
    query: getPageQuery,
    variables: { slug: slug },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing variables to external queries example:

```
const GET_DOG_PHOTO = gql`
  query Dog($breed: String!) {
   dog(breed: $breed) {
    id
    displayImage
   }
  }`;


function DogPhoto({ breed }) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DOG_PHOTO, {
  variables: { breed },
});
```

For more details check this below link

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries